# Detecting click everywhere except on selected element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a `header` section which contains a submenu.

When a user click outside of `header`, I'm looking to hide the submenu.

For now, I'm simply trying to `console.log` when clicking anywhere except when clicking on the `header`.

I've seen similar articles on SO, however, they don't work in my instance.

My `console.log`'s are still appearing when I click on the `header`?

```js
$(function () {
  // $('html:not(.globalHeader)').click(function(event){
  //   event.stopPropagation();
  //   console.log("click");
  // });

  $("body")
    .not(".globalHeader")
    .on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("click");
    });
});
```

```css
header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<body>
  <header class="globalHeader">Header</header>
  <div class="spacer">Spacer</div>
</body>
```

Comment: i suggest you rather listen to the `mouseout` event on the `header` element, and then when that happens just hide the header, its easier to do it this way

Comment: `$("body").not(".globalHeader")` is *all body elements that don't have class globalHeader* - it's unlikely you have `<body class=globalHeader>` so this is just `$("body")`.  You *might* have tried `$("body *").not(".globalHeader")` but that will add a click event to *every* element (except globalHeader), including those inside globalHeader, so, apart from the load, also not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. By doing `$('body').not('.globalHeader')` this returns the body element and adds the click event to it, so any inner element will trigger the click event, you need to filter out the header, so see #2
2. I switched to using the overload of `.on` and setting the 2nd parameter to `:not(.globalHeader)` and it works as intended, this adds a filter to the click event on the body and becomes a delegated event [jQuery.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

**EDIT:**

3. I added to my answer to modify the callback function to check for descendants of the header and return false if it's a descendant and also added a sample span for testing purposes.

```js
$(function () {
    $('body').on("click", ":not(.globalHeader)", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       //check to see if this is a descendant of the header
       if($(this).closest('.globalHeader').length)
           return false;

       console.log("click");
    });
});
```

```css
header {
   padding: 20px 0;
   background: black;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.spacer {
   height: 100vh;
   background: lightblue;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin-top: 10px;
}
  .globalHeader > span:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

 <body>
    <header class="globalHeader">Header<br/><span>Click Me I'm A Header Child</span></header>
    <div class="spacer">Spacer</div>
 </body>
```

Comment: I think this will fail if you click on a child of `.globalHeader`, you might want to check for `.closest()`